# Specify kubectl client version installed via gcloud SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubectl

I probably missed this in the docs somewhere, but since I haven't found it yet, I'll ask: How can I specify the version of `kubectl` CLI when installing with the gcloud SDK?

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.9-2+4a03651a7e7e04", GitCommit:"4a03651a7e7e04a0021b2ef087963dfb7bd0a17e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-16T19:08:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.7-gke.24", GitCommit:"2ce02ef1754a457ba464ab87dba9090d90cf0468", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-12T22:05:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
$ gcloud components update

All components are up to date.
$ which kubectl
/Users/me/Projects/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl
$ which gcloud
/Users/me/Projects/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
$ ls -nL /Users/me/Projects/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin | grep kubectl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 501  20  44296840 Aug 16 12:08 kubectl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 501  20  54985744 Apr 30 21:56 kubectl.1.11
-rwxr-xr-x   1 501  20  56860112 Jul  7 21:34 kubectl.1.12
-rwxr-xr-x   1 501  20  44329928 Aug  5 02:52 kubectl.1.13
-rwxr-xr-x   1 501  20  48698616 Aug  5 02:55 kubectl.1.14
-rwxr-xr-x   1 501  20  48591440 Aug  5 02:57 kubectl.1.15
```

So I'm using the `gcloud`-installed `kubectl`, and I see that the version I want is locally installed. The `gcloud components update` command run previously indicated that `kubectl` would be set to the default version of 1.13, but I haven't caught any indication of how to change the default version.

I *imagine* I could create a link, or copy the version I want onto `Users/me/Projects/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl`, but I'm leary of messing with the managed environs of `gcloud`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whelp, I went ahead and ran the following

```
KUBE_BIN=$(which kubectl)
rm $KUBE_BIN
ln ~/googlecloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl.1.15 $KUBE_BIN
```

and now i get

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.2", GitCommit:"f6278300bebbb750328ac16ee6dd3aa7d3549568", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-05T09:23:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

and everything seems to be working just fine...

Answer (score 2):

## GKE only

Do not change `kubectl` version if you're working only with GKE, because `kubectl` supports *only one version forward and backward skew*.
For example, if you use `kubectl` 1.16 against GKE 1.14, you may experience some bugs, such as `--watch` flag is not working properly.
`gcloud` provides just the right version for the current version of GKE.

## Multiple cluster versions

### explicit version

If you're working with different Kubernetes cluster, I'd suggest using the `gcloud` version of `kubectl` as a default one. For any specific version of `kubectl`, just create a dir `~/bin/kubectl`, put there `kubectl1.15`, `kubectl1.16`, etc. and add the dir to your `PATH`.
With such setup you can explicitly use appropriate version:

```bash
$ # Working with GKE
$ kubectl ...
$ # Working with K8s 1.15
$ kubectl1.15 ...
```

### implicit version

Using [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) you can make switching between versions transparent.
There are many ways of doing this, here is on example.
Let's say you have a project which requires `kubectl` 1.15. Inside the project dir create `env/bin` subdir and link there all binaries you need (`kubectl1.15`, `helm2`, etc.), create `.envrc` file with the following content:

```bash
export PATH="$(PWD)/env/bin:${PATH}"
```

Run `direnv allow` in the project dir (it's needed only once for any new `.envrc`). After that you'll have all binaries from `env/bin` in your path.
And then, in the dir and all subdirs:

```bash
$ # Invokes kubectl 1.15
$ kubectl ...
$ # Invokes Helm 2
$ helm ...
```